# Large numbers in HTML canvas translate result in strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to figure out why, when I give large a large number to the x component of a translate() call on an HTML canvas, rectangles no longer seem to draw at the appropriate coordinates.

In the example below, the two rectangles that are drawn differ only by 1 in the x component. Therefore, I would expect their left edges to be only one pixel apart. As you can see in Firefox and Chrome, that is not what happens.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function go() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if(canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.translate(-1000000000, -500);
                ctx.fillStyle = '#F00'
                ctx.fillRect(1000000033, 520, 100, 200);
                ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
                ctx.fillRect(1000000032, 720, 100, 200);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="go();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the same example ready to look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/pQst6/

I also made an animated version. http://jsfiddle.net/ry35e/ As you can see, the drawing starts normal, but as the x parameter to the translate method increases, it proceeds to have weirder and weirder behavior.

Both Firefox and Chrome appear to behave the same, so it seems like expected behavior, not a browser bug. I am guessing it is some kind of precision problem. Do you agree/disagree?

If it is some kind of precision problem with canvas, I am guessing I will have to find or implement my own transformation matrix and wrap it around the canvas context. I'm sure it wouldn't be very hard to make, but does anybody know of a javascript library that does such transformations (with pop, push, etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deviations occur when you invoke `fillRect` with the integer 2^24 (16 777 216) or greater. This also happens to be the largest **integer** you can express with single precision. The working draft states support for double precision (2^53) but apparently that's not the case (yet). The Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` states support for only single precision (float).

- Single precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision
- Double precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision
- Working draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/
- MDN Docs: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#fillRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#fillRect%28%29)

Comment: This also seems to have the unfortunate consequence that things that should be completely clipped from the visible canvas sometimes aren't. For example a line from (10, bigNumber) to (11, biggerNumber).